# RuntimeException: Unable to start activity when requesting action bar

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, runtimeexception

I am getting the following warning and exception:

> IllegalStateException This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>
> RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mdinfosystem.mymobileapp/com.mdinfosystem.mymobileapp.Bill_Payment}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: please provide more information. Output log isn't enough to help you

Comment: I guess you are creating a duplication of the action bar which is not allowed, so you are suggestes to use Toolbar, whoch duplication is allowed

Comment: a little piece of code make it more clear

Comment: No code. No real fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using toolbar, specify `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`as parent in your activity's styles.xml. And in your activity simply use this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**Note:** Your activity should extend AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

It actually tells you what to do in the

**logCat**:

> set windowActionBar to false in your theme

Go to your `styles.xml` and add:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Comment: style.xml  <style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

Comment: ok so you are using name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> </style>!! NOTICE android:windowActionBar is not the same as: windowActionBar so include it as: <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>  and it will work.